# Courses Or Programs To Get Good Overview Of Ecommerce (Not Online)

Tags: e-commerce

Can anybody tell me a good place or certification/training I could go to enhance my knowledge of the eCommerce. I am a professional web developer but i want to learn more about eCommerce from both business and technical perspective?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few degrees at University that would give you a good grounding in e-commerce - both technically and from a business perspective.

I am not sure where you are based, but for example have a look the [MSc in Information Systems (E-commerce)](http://www.postgraduatesearch.com/kingston-university/52411000/postgraduate-course.htm) at [Kingston University](http://www.kingston.ac.uk/).